How to merge a hot and cold observable of the same source while avoiding duplicates efficiently?
I have a source of elements. It can be queried and it publishes events when elements are added. In other words, I can make a cold observable from the query results, and a hot observable from the event.
One approach is to merge the cold and the hot.
var o = cold.Merge(hot);
It works, but it could miss elements if they were emitted between the cold and hot observables being subscribed to.
So the other approach is the merge the hot and the cold.
var o = hot.Merge(cold);
This works too and avoids missing elements, but it would produce duplicates when elements were emitted from the hot observable before the cold observable was subscribed to.
What about filtering out indistinct elements?
var o = hot.Merge(cold).Distinct()
This solves the problem, but it will maintain a growing list of elements to check for distinctness. I'm interesting in find a way to accomplish the behaviour of using Distinct, but without using more and more memory over time.
I believe the solution is something like:
Subscribe a subject to the hot observable. Subscribe the cold observable to the observer. Pause the subject (?), then replay the subject to the observer, but with the check for distinctness. Finally, unpause (or however that would work) the subject and subscribe it to the observer (without distinctness check).
Below is sample code that demonstrates the behaviours described above. You can run it here if you don't have a compiler available.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

var strategies = new[]
{
    WarmObservable.WithMissesFrom<Int32>,
    WarmObservable.WithDuplicatesFrom,
    WarmObservable.WithCorrectButHighMemoryUsageFrom,
    //WarmObservable.From
};
foreach (var strategy in strategies)
{
    var observed = new List<Int32>();
    var nums = new ObservableAddOnlyCollection<Int32>();
    var warm = strategy(nums, nums.Added);
    const Int32 max = 1_000_000;
    Parallel.For(0, max, i =>
    {
        nums.Add(i);
        if (i == max / 2)
            warm.Subscribe(observed.Add);
    });
    Console.WriteLine($"{observed.Count:N0} elements observed using {strategy.Method.Name}.");
}

public sealed class ObservableAddOnlyCollection<T> : IObservable<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> items = new();
    private event Action<T> added = _ => {};

    public IObservable<T> Added => Observable.FromEvent<T>(h => added += h, h => added -= h);
    public void Add(T item) { lock (items) items.Add(item); added.Invoke(item); }
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer) => ToList().ToObservable().Subscribe(observer);
    private List<T> ToList() { lock (items) return items.ToList(); }
}

public static class WarmObservable
{
    public static IObservable<T> WithMissesFrom<T>(IObservable<T> cold, IObservable<T> hot)
    {
        return cold.Merge(hot);
    }
    
    public static IObservable<T> WithDuplicatesFrom<T>(IObservable<T> cold, IObservable<T> hot)
    {
        return hot.Merge(cold);
    }
    
    public static IObservable<T> WithCorrectButHighMemoryUsageFrom<T>(IObservable<T> cold, IObservable<T> hot)
    {
        return hot.Merge(cold).Distinct();
    }
    
    public static IObservable<T> From<T>(IObservable<T> cold, IObservable<T> hot)
    {
        // merge a cold observable with a hot observable, without losing any elements and without duplicating any elements
        // also don't require an increasing memory footprint to distinguish duplicates
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


Please edit your question to include a [mcve],which shows the problem you have or you think you have. We don't see the hot observable you have, the cold observable you have, how you consume the observables and how async is playing a role here (if any).

I'd really love to so see the [mcve] here too. The description seems to suggest that you're getting suggests that you have a slow subscription. You need to show us the code!

I've rewritten the question to be clear and hopefully not invoke need for a reproducible example code.

@NickStrupat - Did you read the [mcve] page?

There is no difference between cold.Merge(hot) and hot.Merge(cold) regardining missing hot values.

Huh? One must be subscribed before the other, unless subscriptions use some global lock or something. AFAIK they do not.

@NickStrupat - Can you provide a [mcve]? It'll then be made clear.

I've added sample code that demonstrates the behaviour in question.

@NickStrupat - Now I'm trying to figure out what you're code is doing. It's really an unusual way of testing.

@NickStrupat - You code seems to prove that Parallel.For doesn't output all i in sequence. When I replace it with a normal for the code works fine. I don't think you're testing what you think you're testing.

The Parallel.For with the subscription happening in the middle demonstrates how simply merging the hot and cold observables does not account for the possibility of an element being published to the hot observable during the subscription process.

Did you run the code?

@NickStrupat - Correct, there are no guarantees that values produced during the subscription process will end up as outputted values. That should be entirely expected. That's why it's best to create subscriptions that are long-running. I don't think your code demonstrates that, in any case. Parallel.For just makes the system non-deterministic.

Did you read the question? I'm asking how to accomplish hot.Merge(cold).Distinct() without the risk of Distinct() using tons of memory in a long-running subscription. The behavior, as I said in the question and demonstrated in the sample code, is already correct. Thank you for your time and effort thus far though!

Again, the Parallel.For is used solely to manifest the race condition that I described in the question. If cold is subscribed first, the observer can miss elements. If the hot is subscribed first, the observer can receive duplicates.

@NickStrupat - Yes, because of the Parallel.For and not because of the observables. The observables work as expected.

@NickStrupat - Internally Distinct uses private readonly HashSet<TKey> _hashSet;. You cannot avoid a lot of memory usage if you have a long running observable that you much ensure only produces distinct values. You would have to craft your own strategy to avoid Distinct.

Yes, my question is asking how to craft that strategy. I figured it out though. Thanks again!

I realized that implementing a wrapper IObserver<T> class makes it trivial to turn off the distinct check once the cold observable has been enumerated.
Here's the working solution
public static class WarmObservable
{
    public static IObservable<T> From<T>(IObservable<T> cold, IObservable<T> hot, IEqualityComparer<T> ec)
    {
        // merge a cold observable with a hot observable, without losing any elements and without duplicating any elements
        // also don't require an increasing memory footprint to distinguish duplicates
        return new IgnoreDuplicatesUntilColdCompletesObservable<T>(cold, hot, ec);
    }
    
    private sealed class IgnoreDuplicatesUntilColdCompletesObservable<T>(IObservable<T> cold, IObservable<T> hot, IEqualityComparer<T> ec) : IObservable<T>
    {
        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
        {
            var o = new DistinctObserver(observer, ec);
            return hot.Merge(cold.Finally(() => o.OnColdCompleted())).Subscribe(o);
        }
    
        private sealed class DistinctObserver(IObserver<T> o, IEqualityComparer<T> ec) : IObserver<T>
        {
            private HashSet<T>? set = new(ec);

            public void OnColdCompleted() => Interlocked.Exchange(ref set, null);

            public void OnCompleted() => o.OnCompleted();
            public void OnError(Exception error) => o.OnError(error);

            public void OnNext(T value)
            {
                if (set is not null && Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref set, null, null) is {} x)
                {
                    if (x.Add(value))
                    {
                        o.OnNext(value);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    o.OnNext(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Optimization explanation:
The "normal" check of set is not null is before the interlocked check as an optimization. Once set has been assigned null, that value will be propagated to the CPU cache when it is read by interlocked, therefore it doesn't have to do the interlocked read anymore.
